# ORA-29273 HTTP request failed when using UTL_HTTP in Autonomous Database

Tags: oracle, oracle-autonomous-db

I'm working on a project where I'm trying to use UTL_HTTP in my ATP instance (Shared Exadata Infrastructure).

I have created the network ACL as follows:

```
BEGIN
   DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.APPEND_HOST_ACE(
         host => 'fa-saasfaprod1.fa.ocs.oraclecloud.com',
         ace =>  xs$ace_type(privilege_list => xs$name_list('http'),
                             principal_name => 'FENIRACL',
                             principal_type => xs_acl.ptype_db));
END;
/
```

However, when I run utl_http.begin_request() procedure, it fails:

```
UTL_HTTP.BEGIN_REQUEST(url, 'GET', 'HTTP/1.1') 
ORA-29273: HTTP request failed 
ORA-24247: network access denied by access control list (ACL)
```

How can I get utl_http working in Autonomous Database? Is it not supported?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, Autonomous Database on Shared Exadata Infrastructure (ADB-S) supports UTL_HTTP calls with certain restrictions listed in [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/autonomous-database/adbsa/appendix-database-pl-sql-packages-restrictions.html#GUID-829A7D07-1EA4-4F59-AA60-F780FABAFDEC). For example, only HTTPS connections are allowed and the URL must be accessible over the Internet. Also, an important step seems to be missing in the script above, which is to call UTL_HTTP.SET_WALLET('') procedure before UTL_HTTP.BEGIN_REQUEST:

```
BEGIN
   DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.APPEND_HOST_ACE(
         host => 'fa-saasfaprod1.fa.ocs.oraclecloud.com',
         ace =>  xs$ace_type(privilege_list => xs$name_list('http'),
                             principal_name => 'FENIRACL',
                             principal_type => xs_acl.ptype_db));

   UTL_HTTP.SET_WALLET('');

   UTL_HTTP.BEGIN_REQUEST(url, 'GET', 'HTTP/1.1');
END;
/
```